# Can not get UIScrollView to Scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have embedded two UIViews into a Scroll View and I would like to be able to scroll to the second one though it will not work like it used to when i used previous versions before 7.

It looks like the below:

[image: UIScrollViewError]

Is this something i can fix in the Storyboard or programmatically? Either way how do i achieve an end result that can scroll up and down through content even if i added more UIViews stacked.

Comment: If it won't scroll, check the content size of the scroll view.

Comment: can you put that as an answer and i can accept it, thank you!

Comment: @AdamPro13 hey if i opened a chat could you help me with something real quick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it won't scroll, check the content size of your scroll view.